# source from within emacs to load environmental variables

Tags: bash, emacs, elisp, zsh

I have different environmental variables in different files, and usually use `source` to load/unload these. Now I want to change my environmental variables while using emacs. Is there any way to `source`from within emacs?

Comment: Which process do you wish to change the environment of?

Comment: I want to change PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, some INCLUDE_PATH, etc, for different projects while using emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the environment of Emacs itself (which will be inherited by all commands run by it, like compilation commands or shells), I use the following setup:

1. in the emacs init file, the following snippets defines (and calls) a function which starts the server and exports its name in the `EMACS_SERVER` environment variable.

   ```lisp
   (defun my/server-start ()
     "Start an emacs server using an automatically generated name.

   If an emacs server is already running, it is restarted.
   The EMACS_SERVER environment variable is set, so that child processes
   can know which emacs server to contact."

     (if (and (boundp 'server-process)
              server-process
              (memq (process-status server-process) '(connect listen open run)))
         ;; There is already an instance running; just restart it
         (server-start)

       ;; Start a new server
       (let ((i       0)
             (max-try 100)
             (ok      nil))
         (while (and (< i max-try)
                     (not ok))
           (setq server-name (format "server%d" i))
           (setq i (1+ i))
           (unless (server-running-p server-name)
             (setq ok t)))
         (if (>= i max-try)
             (display-warning 'my/server-start
                              "Could not find any unused server name."
                              :warning)
           (message "Starting server with name %s." server-name)
           (server-start))))
     (setenv "EMACS_SERVER" server-name))

   (my/server-start)
   ```
2. in my `~/.bashrc` file, the following function allows sourcing a shell script and exporting the resulting environment to the emacs server referenced by `$EMACS_SERVER`:

   ```sh
   E-source () 
   { 
       ( if [ -n "$1" ]; then
           source "$1";
       fi;
       export | perl -pn -e 's/^declare -x //;' -e 's/([^=]+)=(.*)$/(setenv "$1" $2)/' | while read line; do
           emacsclient -s ${EMACS_SERVER} -e "$line";
       done )
   }
   ```
3. all this being set up, when I want to develop in a project, I open a shell/term/multi-term buffer and while in it, I run

   ```
   E-source my-env.sh
   ```

   before running the compilation commands I need for developping in this particular project.

All this is somewhat complex, but I found it less error-prone than endlessly prefixing all compilation commands with `source my-env.sh`, and also sourcing the environment in all shell/term/multi-term buffers.

Comment: I have heard of emacs-server but never used it. I will give it a try. Thanks for your answer!